# No such element Exception. class name with double__

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to get the text under the  tag. That is Arduus, Gstaad, Switzerland. I tried with the classname and also with xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("chalet-details__title"));
String chaletTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h1[@class='chalet-details_title']")).getText();
```

But its giving `NoSuchElementException`. The `classname` has double underscore(`__`)  .Is it because of that not working? Can anyone help me with this?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="chalet-details__title">
       <span class="chalet-details__title-property">Arduus</span>,
       <a class="chalet-details__title-resort" href="/ski-               resorts/switzerland/gstaad">Gstaad</a>,
       <a class="chalet-details__title-country" href="/ski- resorts/switzerland">Switzerland</a>
    </h1>
                <div class="chalet-details__rating">
                    <div class="chalet-details__wrapper">
                        <span class="chalet-details__star" style="width: 108px;"></span>
                        <span class="chalet-details__mask"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try this to get Arduus.         By.xpath("//span[@class='chalet-details__title-property']")).getText();

Comment: Thanks Andersson but i want all the text under the <h1> tag.

Comment: like this Arduus, Gstaad, Switzerland

Comment: By.xpath("//span[@class='chalet-details__title-property']")).getText();

Comment: By.xpath("//span[@class='chalet-details__title-property']/a")).getText();

Comment: By.xpath("//span[@class='chalet-details__title-property']/a[1]")).getText();

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("h1.chalet-details__title"))
```

I just tried this and it worked fine with the provided html, if this still fails for you, can you verify that there aren't any iframes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Both your locators are OK, but you might need to wait for your element to be present in `DOM`:

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20 );
String chaletTitle = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("chalet-details__title"))).getText();
```

Another reason for `NoSuchElementException`: your element could be located inside an `iframe`, so you need to switch to that frame before handling target element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeNameOrId");
```

If it has no attributes as `id` or `name`:

```
WebElement someFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@someAttr='someValue']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(someFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the text under h1 tag find all elements using locator as follows:

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h1.chalet-details__title > *")); //it will find all elements immediately under the h1 tag
```

Now, iterate over the elements.

Complete code:

```
    List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h1.chalet-details__title > *"));

    for(WebElement item : items){
        System.out.println(item.getText());
    }
```